# Encode/escape HTML string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a string that came from a field in my model.

```
# <br />
"This is my title with break &lt;br /&gt; in the middle"
```

I'm rendering it on my view:

```
<p>
  <%= raw @model.title %>
</p>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
<p>
  This is my title with break <br /> in the middle
</p>
```

However, the `<br />` shows up as string and not as html. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Un-escape it, then use html_safe. Enjoy the scripting attacks.

Comment: @DaveNewton Does the html_safe prevents those attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as Dave Newton said, you should unescape then use html_safe. If your html in your model is not complex, you could use CGI.unescapeHTML to unescape. But if it is, I think you should use gem HTMLEntities at http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/

```
<p>
  <%= (CGI.unescapeHTML @model.title).html_safe %>
</p>
```